# Using a CAD template in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, autocad

Is there a simple way to create a "CAD template" for map outputs from ArcGIS as in the image below:

[image]

I'd like to create a standard template and then populate some simple 'fields' with map information (title, scale, date).

Comment: I would like to know more about gis (mapping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:

1- Open ArcMap with a Blank Map.

2- Go to Layout view (the layout must be a simple rectangle, if not you can use Change Layout to select an empty one).

3- in File>Page and Print Setup you can choose the size and orientation of the template.

4- in the Layout view, change the Data Frame dimensions to open sapce for title, scale, date. or just adjust the dimensions to the Layout.

5- Use Draw Tools (Graphic tools) to create the details of the Layout for the title, scale, date, ...

6- Finally Save it as .mxd

7-Done.

and here are some links of how to convert templates into CAD or from CAD templates into Arc:

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1149&t=231001

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/24127

http://www.ehow.com/how_7569173_convert-mxd-dwg.html

Comment: Looks like the most straight-forward was of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Save that mxd to C:/Users/<user name>/AppData/Roaming/ESRI/Desktop10.0/Arcmap/Templates. Then you can access it as a regular template when chosing layout.

Comment: The way I read this is the user wanted to take a CAD template file and convert it into a format that ArcMap can use as a reusable template file.  As far as I can tell, this does not answer that question.

Is there not any way to make that conversion?  All this answer accomplishes is recreating the template from scratch.