# Convert CAD to graphics for layout template in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts, cad, dwg

I've received a CAD template and need to use this as an ArcGIS layout template. I can go to layout view in ArcGIS and "convert features to graphics" as suggested in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32287/using-a-cad-template-in-arcgis).

This answer suggests redrawing all the lines in the CAD template (step 5). Converting CAD features to graphics still means that the graphics have a "spatial" location and will be visible in the data view. Is there a way to divorce a CAD conversion from any spatial information and effectively have it behave as lines drawn using the "draw" toolbar in the layout view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding completely, but in Layout view you can insert the dwg as an object (Insert >Object... >Create from File). This will save you from re-drawing and it definitely won't show up in data view.

[image: simple acad titleblock inserted in layout view]

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. However my objects are just appearing as icons at the moment...

Comment: Okay, worked it out. Instead of "insert > object" I opened Inskape, saved an .svg as .emf in Inkscape, opened the .emf in Inkscape, selected all elements and the ctrl + C, over to the Arc layout and ctrl + V

Comment: Appreciate the follow-up.  I think you just changed my workflow.

Comment: It only comes in as an image so you can't alter the component parts (as far as I've tried) but given ESRI don't offer any support for SVG this is the best workaround I can see.